# Given a permission name, how do I find the PermissionGroup?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to look up the permission group for a permission at runtime (to provide guidance in the UI about how to visit Settings and then enable the permission, after the user has checked the "never ask again" button on the prompt).  So I need the human-readable name for the permission group, but all I have is the machine-readable fully qualified permission string (`Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`).  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getPermissionInfo()` on `PackageManager` returns a `PermissionInfo` given the name of the permission. `PermissionInfo` has a `group` field that contains the group name (`"android.permission-group.CALENDAR"`, a.k.a. `Manifest.permission_group.CALENDAR`).

`getPermissionGroupInfo()` on `PackageManager` returns a `PermissionGroupInfo` for that group name. On that, call `loadLabel()`, supplying the `PackageManager` as input, to get the human-readable name of the permission group.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know how I managed to overlook that group field.

Comment: Since Android 10 this does not work. group="android.permission-group.UNDEFINED"